# arm-none-eabi-gcc build from source with --enable-threads

Tags: compiler-errors, arm-none-eabi-gcc

I am trying to use the arm-none-eabi-gcc and enable the std::mutex and other Thread support on it. I tried to re-compile the compiler from source as I found the source code from [here](https://developer.arm.com/-/media/Files/downloads/gnu-rm/10.3-2021.10/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10.3-2021.10-src.tar.bz2?rev=81b3b1eadff74e0f9b4a6bcb1bd22f0e&hash=4D788E9CB131173F0662347F963B6ED73C28FDA1)

However, I am failing to enable it. Is there any possible way to build it with Thread:posix support enabled?

## What have I tried?

1. Downloaded the source code.
2. Opened the build-toolchain.sh script and changed all the `--disable-threads` to `--enable-threads`
3. Ran the commands as stated in the **`How-to-build-toolchain.pdf`** file and the build finished with error however there is a install_native folder that is created and when I went into it and ran "**arm-none-eabi-gcc -v**" It still gave **`Thread:single`** as the output.

Where am I doing wrong?